# How to dismiss keyboard in IOS Swift from a subview inside a scroll view in the main view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikeyboard

I am having a 2 Subviews inside a scroll view in a main view. Bases on a two buttons in the scroll view the 2sub views will show and hide. Both the subviews have one text field each to enter numbers. the keypad is a num pad. I have implemented `func touchesBegan` and also the `UITapGestureRecognizer` for both the subviews and added the `resignFirstResponder()` as well as  `endEditing(true)`. But still my keyboard does not goes away. I cant find a proper solution for this type of scenario in any forum.

I am using Swift 2.0 xcode7.1.1

Edit: My code ( Since it is a business project i cannot share the full content sorry)

in this code when i touch outside in the `viewAutomatic` the keyboard goes. but when i touch outside in the `viewManual` the keyboard does not goes off. It is so weird for me.

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewScroll: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtNewBid: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtMyMaxBid: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var viewManual: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewAutomatic: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
 let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTapped:")
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        self.viewManual.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
        self.viewAutomatic.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
}
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

 func singleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.viewManual.endEditing(true)
    self.viewAutomatic.endEditing(true)
    self.viewScroll.endEditing(true)
    txtNewBid.resignFirstResponder()
    txtMyMaxBid.resignFirstResponder()

}
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    txtNewBid.resignFirstResponder()
    txtMyMaxBid.resignFirstResponder()
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    // adjusting the scroll view for the keyboard
    let frame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    if( self.viewManual.hidden == true)
    {
        self.viewScroll.frame.size.height -= frame.height 
    }
    else
    {
        self.viewScroll.frame.size.height -= frame.height 
    }
    let bottomOffset: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.txtNewBid.frame.origin.y + self.txtNewBid.frame.size.height)
    self.viewScroll.contentOffset = bottomOffset
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    let frame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    if( self.viewManual.hidden == true)
    {
        self.viewScroll.frame.size.height += frame.height 
    }
    else
    {
        self.viewScroll.frame.size.height += frame.height 
    }

    }
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    txtNewBid.text = ""
    txtMyMaxBid.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are approaching the problem the wrong way. I assume that the controller should be responsible for dismissing the keyboard, but you might try something like this (preferrably on your hosting view controller):

```
yourView.endEditing(true) // boolean parameter specifies whether to force dismissal or not
```

`endEditing(force)` should traverse the view hierarchy and check for any active responders, so this should actually work. Have you checked if you indeed reference the correct view ? Can you add some of your code (Please just the necessary portions) ?

The reason I point out that it's important to call this on your hosting controller's view is that it goes through all the subviews and checks for any active responders.

If you have a reference to the textfield and you know for sure which one it is you can also call

```
yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

I guess that's what `endEditing(force)` does internally, it traverses all the subviews and calls `resignFirstResponder()` on any textField it encounters that also is the first responder.

## EDIT

Due to the fact that the `UIScrollView` will intercept gestures, I would directly add the tap gesture recognizer to the scroll view like so:

```
self.viewScroll.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
```

And then do something like this:

```
func singleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // this should suffice
    self.viewScroll.endEditing(true)
    // or call it on the touched view (in this case the viewScroll)
    // sender.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: @KauthamMurugan can you add a `NSLog("test");` to your tap gesture function to make sure it is called ? If you have a scroll view it might be that it swallows the touches and the tap gesture is not called.

Comment: and by the way, putting all those components into a `UITableView` might be a better solution (especially if you reuse cells => much better performance)

Comment: i can understand you clearly but my issue is a bit complicated. As you can see above i use the same kind of code for both the sub views to dismiss the keyboard. But the dismissal works in one subview `viewAutomatic` but the dismissal does not work in another subview `viewManual` sorry for not being specific earler.

Comment: and sorry tableview is not a better option here according to the project.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan okay, no problem, can you please try logging (or putting a breakpoint) into the tap gesture just to make sure ?

Comment: @KauthamMurugan another note: Always make sure to add a `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)` in `viewWillDisappear` to properly clean up.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan If the viewManual is a subview of your view controller and the tap gesture recognizer function is called then `self.view.endEditing(true)` should normally do the trick (no need to call on each view). Where is the textfield located (which view)?

Comment: I forgot to put the viewWillDisappear block.

Comment: `txtNewBid` is placed in `viewManual` and `txtMyMaxBid` is placed in `viewAutomatic`

Comment: try adding the gesture recognizer on the `viewScroll`scroll view instead.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan i.e. `self.viewScroll.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)` and remove all the other lines to add gesture recognizers

Comment: @KauthamMurugan updated the answer, please try the code from my edit. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks friend. Adding gesture recogniser to the scroll view works perfect.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan You're welcome! Good luck with your project!